# There was an error while trying to load the gem 'pg'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, pg

I'm trying to update my old project to new rails version and I have this error when I'm trying to run it as debug in local

As you can see above I'm using Windows. The project now have the ruby version ruby-2.4.4-p296

I tried to reinstall the gem and run bundle install / update but it doesn't work...

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '0.20.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.7'
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '4.7.0.1'

#gem 'puma'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.4'

gem 'simple_form'

#https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf
gem 'wicked_pdf'

gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-heroku'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.8.2'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:   https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'


group :doc do
    # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
    gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development, :test do
    # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
    #gem install rdoc -v '6.0.4'gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.6.1.beta2, debase 0.2.2, file filtering is supported) listens on 0.0.0.0:3970
Uncaught exception: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'pg'.
Gem Load Error is: undefined method `add_dll_directory' for RubyInstaller:Module
Backtrace for gem load error is:
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/pg-0.20.0-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/pg-0.20.0-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:24:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/pg-0.20.0-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.17.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.17.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.17.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.17.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.17.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.17.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.17.0.pre.1/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
C:/Users/Adrian/RubymineProjects/peluqueria-inspinia/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Users/Adrian/RubymineProjects/peluqueria-inspinia/bin/rails:4:in `require'
C:/Users/Adrian/RubymineProjects/peluqueria-inspinia/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta2/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:88:in `debug_load'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta2/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:88:in `debug_program'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta2/bin/rdebug-ide:130:in `<top (required)>' -e:1:in `load'-e:1:in `<main>'
```

Bundler Error Backtrace:

```
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.17.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:84:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.17.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `block (2 levels) in require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.17.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.17.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.17.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.17.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.17.0.pre.1/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
C:/Users/Adrian/RubymineProjects/peluqueria-inspinia/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Users/Adrian/RubymineProjects/peluqueria-inspinia/bin/rails:4:in `require'
C:/Users/Adrian/RubymineProjects/peluqueria-inspinia/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

Process finished with exit code 0

I think the problem is the version of the gem 'pg' but I don't know what version I should put

Comment: Here is the list of gem versions so you can try with: https://rubygems.org/gems/pg/versions  also you should first try to install gem  as gem install pg and if thats finish okay then run bundle install for rest of gem install

Comment: Are you actually deploying to a windows server? If not I would use docker or some other virtualization tool and develop on the same OS you are deploying to. It will most likely save you a bunch of headaches.

Comment: Thanks to all answers, yes Max, I'm deploying it to a Windows server thats the problem.. To be honest, I think the best way to solve this is do a docker container as you said

Answer (score 1):

pg-0.20.0 is not compatible with more recent RubyInstaller versions. You'll have to update to at least pg-0.21.0. Probably it's best to remove the version requirement for pg in the `Gemfile`, so that it's updated to the latest compatible version on `bundler update`. See also the [pg changelog](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/blob/master/History.rdoc#v0210-2017-06-12-michael-granger-gedfaeriemudorg).